# Deserialize json with c# with random root names

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a json file which has random names in roots but same structure in child elements. I would like to get all the child elements in an array or a list.

Sample json file :

```
{  
   "-LeHl495vL6vh-8CaLbD":{  
      "apiKey":"sr-tr-137-beea04e44cb452ba0da0ca090b7e61b4ec6ffc69"
   },
   "-LeHl6jrhUEMb7slZcpB":{  
      "apiKey":"sr-tr-137-aef7a23095c0c7baef1ef681bdd8bf9756ac2a17"
   }
}
```

I have tried these classes but could not do it.

```
public class RequestedReport
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<ReportData>> ReportDatas { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportData
    {
        public string apiKey { get; set; }
    }
```

So my expected output from deserialization is like List which contains all the apiKeys in json file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there multiple `apiKey` entries in each object or just the one?

Comment: Just one api key in each node.

Comment: The Jon has your answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to me like your JSON represents a `Dictionary<string, ReportData>` directly. There's no wrapper object, and no lists involved. If you deserialize your JSON to that type, it should be fine. Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var reports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ReportData>>(json);

        foreach (var pair in reports)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value.ApiKey}");
        }
    }
}

public class ReportData
{
    [JsonProperty("apiKey")]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

If you just want the list of API keys, and you don't care about the field names associated with them, you can use:

```
var apiKeys = reports.Values.Select(x => x.ApiKey).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this work if the random values are not guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: I think the deserialization into a dictionary would fail for duplicate keys, and I see nothing in your original question that promises uniqueness for this value. It certainly looks unique, but I've learned not to trust data.

Comment: @Broom Yes, this wouldn't work for non-unique values. I believe JSON.Net would take the last `apiKey` for each key.

Comment: @Broom: From RFC 7159: "When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable." In other words, anything producing such JSON is really just *asking* for trouble.